# how to delete a name from a panda series

Tags: pandas, series

I have two series pandas and would like to make a tuple with these two series.  I need to be like this:

```
print(serie1,serie2)

sympathetic     0.074475
 healer          0.074475
 aaniye          0.074475
 dependable      0.074475
 companion       0.074475
 listener        0.074475
 athletic        0.074475
 exterminator    0.074475
 psychiatrist    0.074475
 pest            0.074475
 determined      0.074475
 chef            0.074475
 courageous      0.074475
 stylist         0.074475
 psychologist    0.074475
 organizer       0.074475
 pudunga         0.074475
 venaam          0.074475
 diwali          0.091250
 mornings        0.091250
 dtype: float64, 146tf150p    1.000000
 havent       1.000000
 home         1.000000
 okie         1.000000
 thanx        1.000000
 er           1.000000
 anything     1.000000
 lei          1.000000
 nite         1.000000
 yup          1.000000
 thank        1.000000
 ok           1.000000
 where        1.000000
 beerage      1.000000
 anytime      1.000000
 too          1.000000
 done         1.000000
 645          1.000000
 tick         0.980166
 blank        0.932702
```

I need to get the same result as above, but I have the following result, the name 'tfidf'of the series is displayed:

```
(sympathetic     0.074475
 healer          0.074475
 aaniye          0.074475
 dependable      0.074475
 companion       0.074475
 listener        0.074475
 athletic        0.074475
 exterminator    0.074475
 psychiatrist    0.074475
 pest            0.074475
 determined      0.074475
 chef            0.074475
 courageous      0.074475
 stylist         0.074475
 psychologist    0.074475
 organizer       0.074475
 pudunga         0.074475
 venaam          0.074475
 diwali          0.091250
 mornings        0.091250
 Name: tfidf, dtype: float64, 146tf150p    1.000000
 yup          1.000000
 645          1.000000
 done         1.000000
 too          1.000000
 anytime      1.000000
 beerage      1.000000
 ok           1.000000
 thank        1.000000
 where        1.000000
 nite         1.000000
 lei          1.000000
 anything     1.000000
 er           1.000000
 thanx        1.000000
 okie         1.000000
 home         1.000000
 havent       1.000000
 tick         0.980166
 blank        0.932702
 Name: tfidf, dtype: float64)
```

How do I delete the name tf idf and show it according to the first example considered correct for my case?

Comment: Something like `print(df1.to_string(), df2.to_string())`, perhaps.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood you and you just want to avoid displaying the name, not all the metadata in the last row. In that case try `series1.name = series2.name = None` and print again.

Comment: wow that's cool !! It is working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

```
#The name of the index column of the series is deleted.
del series1.index.name
del series2.index.name

#The name of the series is omited
series1.name = series2.name = None

#This should return a tuple of two series
In:(series1, series2)


Out:(sympathetic     0.074475
 healer          0.074475
 aaniye          0.074475
 dependable      0.074475
 companion       0.074475
 listener        0.074475
 athletic        0.074475
 exterminator    0.074475
 psychiatrist    0.074475
 pest            0.074475
 determined      0.074475
 chef            0.074475
 courageous      0.074475
 stylist         0.074475
 psychologist    0.074475
 organizer       0.074475
 pudunga         0.074475
 venaam          0.074475
 diwali          0.091250
 mornings        0.091250
 dtype: float64, 146tf150p    1.000000
 yup          1.000000
 645          1.000000
 done         1.000000
 too          1.000000
 anytime      1.000000
 beerage      1.000000
 ok           1.000000
 thank        1.000000
 where        1.000000
 nite         1.000000
 lei          1.000000
 anything     1.000000
 er           1.000000
 thanx        1.000000
 okie         1.000000
 home         1.000000
 havent       1.000000
 tick         0.980166
 blank        0.932702
 dtype: float64)
```

Comment: Fixed your answer, one assignment statement should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the dtype also printed but just the values, you just have to do

`print(serie1.values, serie2.values)`

Comment: Sorry, it's not work. The result of your suggestion was just numbers, strings are omitted.: [ 0.07447452  0.07447452  0.07447452  0.07447452  0.07447452  0.07447452
  0.07447452  0.07447452  0.07447452  0.07447452  0.07447452  0.07447452
  0.07447452  0.07447452  0.07447452  0.07447452  0.07447452  0.07447452
  0.09124961  0.09124961] [ 1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.
  1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.          1.
  1.          1.          1.          1.          0.9801659   0.93270158]

Comment: The suggestion worked from @cs95. I did my_series =  my_series.name = None. The name of the series is omited. thanks for you contribuition! ;-)